What makes human beings living?
I'm a philosophy newbie, and it's my first time here, so if there's anything "incorrect" about my question, please let me know. :-)
When we look at the basic structure of human beings, we’re made of carbon and hydrogen molecules, which are essentially non-living. If we’re made of non-living components, is it correct to classify ourselves as living? What separates us from a book, which is made of almost the same components?
Is there a fallacy in my logic?
Edit: I'd like to clarify what separates us from non-living things, especially since we're made of the same molecules.

You're not actually made of specific atoms: your body keeps changing its material basis via ingestion and excretion. Your body is a river, a flux of matter.

Hmm, sounds interesting. Can you be more specific; like can you elaborate on what you mean by 'flux of matter'?

Some 70% of your body is water. This water is in flux: you sweat, and then you replace the lost water by drinking. Same applies to other body components, except they are replaced less frequently than water is. Today, you are not made of the same atoms that composed uou yesterday. We are Theseus ships.

Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification! :)

I've edited the question.

The fallacy in this reasoning has a name, the fallacy of division, inferring that something true of a whole must also be true of its parts. Water is made of molecules, they are not wet, yet the water is wet; a circle is made of points, they are not round, yet the circle is round, etc. Properties of wholes depend not only on parts they are made of, but also on how those parts are put together.

@Conifold, thank you for pointing that out! I knew there was something wrong with the question.

This question is similar to: How can nature without self-awareness and intelligence create living beings with self-awareness and intelligence?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@CriglCragl, it's quite similar. I just need clarification on what makes human beings 'living'.

Persistent patterns, is the answer. Living organisms are stable dissipative systems, like say the swirl as water goes down a plughole, or a wind zephyr. David Krakauer has a framing of complex systems (ie those in which emergence occurs), that they are about dissipative systems which alter behaviour in response to interactions with the world, which he calls teleonomic matter. It's a route to a ground-up picture that can identify a spectrum from non-living to living.

This is such a helpful explanation. I really appreciate it! @CriglCragl

@conifold: That's worth making an Answer.

Note that the question immediately generalizes to what makes living things living. And some fun games in terms of trying to find counterexamples of things that we know are not living but which challenge the definitions we are using. Can you prove that a given rock isn't a life form that just metabolizes too slowly for us to observe it? (Yes, but not trivially.)

Possible duplicate of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/107150/what-is-lost-upon-death

The answer to such a basic question is best looked up in a biology book.
The second best method is to start with a simple online source like Life. There you find the proposal of seven standard characteristics of life together with some discussion of the context.
If these sources trigger further questions, please ask a specific question. This blog prompts to focus each post onto a single question, see also here.
